# Writer s3 iterations to a csv file by separted by column using Boto3/Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, boto3, writer

I am writing my output to a csv file. Here is my output:

```
bucket_name | s3_key_path

value        , value

bucket_name | s3_key_path

value        , value
```

I want the output to be:

```
bucket_name | s3_key_path

value        , value

value        , value

value        , value
```

Here is my code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
    )

bucket1=s3.Bucket(BUCKET)


def load_into_csv():

    with open('/my_path/ms3_files_V2.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        header=['bucket_name', 's3_key_path']
        for objects in bucket1.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
            bucket_name=  '{}' .format(bucket1.name)
            the_key= '{}' .format(objects.key)
            dd={'bucket_name': bucket_name, 's3_key_path': the_key}
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in dd:
                print(row)
                writer.writerow(row)
load_into_csv()
```

Any idea as to why my output keeps putting the headers for each value above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the writing of the header before the `for` loop:

```
        header = ['bucket_name', 's3_key_path']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
        writer.writeheader()
        for objects in bucket1.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
```

Otherwise the header will be written for each object in the bucket.